# About Spring Data jpa (+ Hibernate) "findOne" generated SQL query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a main jpa entity associated with multiple code/label entities.

When I use `findOne(mainEntityId)`, I can see Hibernate is creating a SQL query with multiple "left join", which is what I would have done by hand.

But, when I use `findByName(name)` ("name" being a secondary unique key for main entity) Hibernate will issue one query with no join + one query per code/label entity. I guess this may a better strategy if you have many "main entities", but in my case I have only one result, and I would like to tweak mapping or repository so I get the "left joins" for my single result "findByName" query.

Is there a way to do this, and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [@EntityGraph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph) annotation or explicitly defining a query with [fetch join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-fetch-join-example):

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "children")
Parent findByName(String name);

@Query("select p from Parent p join fetch p.children")
Parent findByName(String name);
```

Comment: I've just tested, this works great, all main entities and many-to-one data are now fetched in one single SQL request using "left join". I see one problem though, if I have 2 different graphs for "findByName" for 2 different use cases, can I still use this "@EntityGraph" annotation ? Can I add random characters after "ByName" to distinguish my 2 graphs ? (findByNameForContactManagement(...), findByNameForOrderManagement(...))

Comment: @Tristan you can [name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) your query methods, for example, `findByName` and `getByName` (they will do the same thing) and use different `@EntityGraph` annotations on them.

Comment: Ok, it would work but this looks like a "hack". Is there a way to have my graph name inside my method name to distinguish them properly ?

Comment: @Tristan No (check the link I've provided...)

Comment: Yes I was not finding anything related in the doc, that's why I was asking. But after a few tries, I've just found an undocumented feature : I can put anything between "find" and "By" which wont be interpreted (except if it's "Distinct"). So for my example use cases, it would be : findForContactManagementByName(...), findForOrderManagementByName(...) annoted with different "@EntityGraph".

Comment: @Tristan Yes you can. I think you want to have add the name of graph after 'By' )